# I assigned a value a variable, but it doesn't show its actual value

Tags: c, variables

So I'm starting to code in C and I just found an error and I can't tell why this is happening to me:
    //variables

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main () {
int x;

printf ("Add a value to variable 'x': ");
scanf ("i%", &x);
printf ("'x' = %i.\n", x);

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

When I compile it it just tells me that the value of X is 0, no matter what value I assigned to it before.

Comment: You made a typo in scanf()'s format string.

Comment: To avoid this sort of error, check return value of `scanf`. You should do that anyway, in case the person types in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your scanf to

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

and it will work. `scanf("i%", &x);` is telling scanf that you want to match a literal 'i' and a literal '%'.

Answer (score 0):

You should use %i instead of i% in the scanf line.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled: it's `"%i"`, not `"i%"`;  and for the `"%d"` vs. `"%i"` there is no difference (that I'm aware of).